# Adobe AEM Forms: inserting XML variable in XSLT Source template

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, aem, livecycle

I'm working with a Process that use one XSLTService Activity to transform XML. It will need to consume both the ordinary XML Source as well as process variables of type String and XML. My problem is that I can't figure out how to inserting process variables of type XML into XSLT Source templates. I have no problem inserting variables of type String.

This is the insert part of my stylesheet:

```
 <xsl:variable name="stringvariable" select="'{$/process_data/@stringVariable$}'"/>
 <xsl:variable name="externalNodes" select="'{$/process_data/inputNodeNames$}'"/>
```

I have tried to insert the data between start- and end-tag of the variable element, but that didn't help. The string variable is inserted and later successfully printed for verification.

I have also created a local variable (with same contents as external) for reference:

```
 <xsl:variable name="internalNodes">
  <root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <block>$.Formularmetadata</block>
   <block>$.Sorteringsdata</block>
   <block>$.Metadata</block>
   <block>$.Verksamhetsdata</block>
  </root>
 </xsl:variable>
```

I then invoke count(exsl:node-set()) on both XML-variables in the template, but only the local have a value above 0.

How can I get this to work?

/BS

PS. This is the full XSL stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="stringvariable" select="'{$/process_data/@stringVariable$}'"/>
 <xsl:variable name="externalNodes" select="'{$/process_data/inputNodeNames$}'"/>
 <xsl:variable name="internalNodes">
  <root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <block>$.Formularmetadata</block>
   <block>$.Sorteringsdata</block>
   <block>$.Metadata</block>
   <block>$.Verksamhetsdata</block>
  </root>
 </xsl:variable>

 <!-- Identity rule.-->
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <!-- Rewrite attribute ref to work with new XML.-->
 <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='bind']/@ref">
  <xsl:value-of select="$stringvariable "/>
  <xsl:value-of select="' Internal'"/><xsl:value-of select="count(exsl:node-set($internalNodes)/root/block)"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="' External'"/><xsl:value-of select="count(exsl:node-set($externalNodes)/root/block)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

After som more experientation I found that if I use a string variable to transfer the data it seams to work. I insert it between a start- and end-tag and then use it after I have embedded it in exsl:node-set() to make it work as XML.

Insertion Point:

```
<xsl:variable name="topNodes">'{$/process_data/@xmlTopNodes$}'</xsl:variable>
```

Usage in template:

```
<xsl:variable name="match" select="exsl:node-set($topNoder)/root/block[starts-with(current(), .)]"/>
```